# Bluetooth and ESPNow don't work together [ESP32]

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, wifi, esp32, hardware, esp-now

I am working with BLE and ESPNow for wireless communication on my project using ESP-WROOM-32.
I got a problem when trying to BLE Scan and ESPNow as a receiver together, seems like ESP32 have hardware limitations, one shared RF Module:  https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/coexist.html

I used two ESP32 for testing, one as a master sending data and other one receiving data on ESPNow, but as soon as BLE start scanning, ESPNow stopped and did not receive any more data.

Has anyone managed to get them to work together?